# Let $S$ be an infinite Set...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb R$ that is bounded above and suppose $\sup S\notin S$. Show that there exists a monotone increasing sequence $\{U_n\}$ with $U_n$ belonging to $S$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n = \sup S$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For each $\epsilon > 0$, $\sup(S) - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $S$, so there is some $x \in S$ such that
$$
\sup(S) - \epsilon < x < \sup(S)
$$
(Note that the second inequality is $<$ because $\sup(S) \notin S$)

Now, for $\epsilon = 1$, choose $x_1$ as above. Now that $\epsilon = 1/2$, then $\max\{\sup(S) - 1/2, x_1\}$ is not an upper bound for $S$, so there is $x_2 \in S$ such that
$$
\max\{\sup(S) - 1/2, x_1\} < x_2 < \sup(S)
$$
Now proceed inductively to find an increasing sequence $(x_n) \in S$ such that
$$
x_n < x_{n+1} \quad\forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
$$
\sup(S) - \frac{1}{n} < x_n < \sup(S) \quad\forall n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
Thus, $x_n \to \sup(S)$

Comment: but how to prove that the limit of the sequence Un is sup S

Comment: @user98792 : I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: For each $n$, there must exist at least one element $a_n$ of $S$ for which

$$\sup{S} - \frac{1}{n} < a_n < \sup{S}$$

The first inequality can be made strict by the definition of the supremum, and the second is strict since $\sup{S} \notin S$.

Now use this sequence to find a monotone increasing subsequence.