# limit point and boundary point!

Tags: real-analysis

If a boundary point of S is not a point of S prove that it is a limit point of S. Prove that a set S belonging to R is closed if and only if S contains all its boundary points.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried and what's giving you trouble? The techniques here are *very* similar to those answering your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531745/let-s-be-an-infinite-set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ![Hope you know thw defination of Boundary point....and understand how i have worked out the problem]
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxsgt.jpg)Hope you know thw defination of Boundary point....and understand how i have worked out the problem